# How to encapsulate local variables in NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans, encapsulation

I want to refactor several local variables into an inner or local class in NetBeans. Is there a way to do this with the refactoring tool, like the `move` tool for encapsulating fields?

E.g.:

```
public double calculate(){
    double a=2;
    double b=3.14159
    return a*b;
}
```

Should become:

```
public double calculate(){
    NumberToCalc num = new NumberToCalc();
    return num.a*num.b;

}

class NumberToCalc{
    double a=2;
    double b=3.14159;
}
```

Or

```
public double calculate(){
    class NumberToCalc{
        double a=2;
        double b=3.14159;
    }

    NumberToCalc num = new NumberToCalc();
    return num.a*num.b;
}
```